# What is the correct way to call scipy.linalg.cython_blas.daxpy?

Tags: python, scipy, cython, blas

I want to do in place vector addition in cython, so I'm using `scipy.linalg.cython_blas.daxpy` .

My syntax is:

```
daxpy(&n_samples, &tmp, &Q[0, ii], &inc, &G[0], &inc)
```

But in [scikit-learn code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/cd_fast.pyx#L248), I read

```
axpy(n_samples, -w[ii], &X_data[ii * n_samples], 1, R_data, 1)
```

where axpy has been defined as daxpy earlier.

Is the & mandatory for the first two variable (int and double respectively) ? Why is there no & for the two first arguments in sklearn code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just the difference between BLAS and CBLAS.

BLAS (which scipy.linalg wraps for you) uses a FORTRAN interface, so most(/all?) arguments (include simple ones such as integers) are passed by pointers.

[Scikit-learn looks to use CBLAS](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/cd_fast.pyx#L112) rather than the scipy.linalg wrappers. CBLAS appears to define an interface that is more natural for C (simple arguments passed by value).

---

Therefore, if you're using the scipy Cython wrappers, you look to be doing it correctly.